# What is a good textbook on statistical genetics for someone without a lot of biology background?

Tags: references, genetics

I am looking for a good book to study from to learn
about statistical genetics. I have no background in
biology, some learning in chemistry, reading some
of Griffith's book on genetic analysis but I am
interested in just statistical genetics.

I have ordered the book reviewed in the most current
edition of AmStat by the fellow from TAM; but I would
like to know if there are any others to use as a backup.
Is Lange too difficult?

Comment: Which book are you referring to in American Statistician? Lange?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to a list of books on statistical genetics from amazon with reviewer rankings and reviews.  I am very familiar with Mark Yang's book because I took a short course from him out of it.  It is easy to read and basic but not very thorough.  I think Laird and Lang are two worth considering.  I am not familiar with any of the others but several of them are reviewed on the site. The list was gotten searching "statistical genetics".  Most but not all of the books on the list match the topic.

http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=statistical+genetics#/ref=sr_pg_1?rh=n%3A283155%2Ck%3Astatistical+genetics&keywords=statistical+genetics&ie=UTF8&qid=1341673697